# error while committing and navigate using ADF popup

Tags: java, jsf, popup, oracle-adf

I insert data into form so transaction becomes dirty and i check for that.

if it's dirty i show popup with options to navigate and commit or navigate with rollback.

i tried dragging a button with same action outside the popup and it worked. so i assume the problem comes from popup!! but i see every thing is normal.

did i miss any thing ?

popup :

```
<af:popup childCreation="immediate" autoCancel="disabled" id="p1" contentDelivery="immediate">
                <af:panelWindow id="pw2" contentWidth="400" title="Warning" closeIconVisible="false">
                    <af:panelGridLayout id="pgl8">
                        <af:gridRow marginTop="5px" height="auto" id="gr3">
                            <af:gridCell marginStart="5px" width="100%" marginEnd="5px" id="gc4">
                                <af:outputText value="SaveFirst" id="ot17"/>
                            </af:gridCell>
                        </af:gridRow>
                        <af:gridRow marginTop="5px" height="auto" marginBottom="5px" id="gr4">
                            <af:gridCell marginStart="5px" width="100%" marginEnd="5px" id="gc5" halign="end">
                                <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl15" layout="horizontal">
                                    <af:button text="NavigateWithCommit" id="b1"
                                               actionListener="#{homeMgr.navigateWithCommit}"/>
                                    <af:button text="NavigateWithRollBack" id="b2"
                                               actionListener="#{homeMgr.navigateWithRollBack}"/>
                                    <af:button text="Cancel" id="b3"
                                               actionListener="#{homeMgr.closeConfimPopup}"/>
                                    <f:facet name="separator">
                                        <af:spacer width="5" height="0" id="s8"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                </af:panelGroupLayout>
                            </af:gridCell>
                        </af:gridRow>
                    </af:panelGridLayout>
                </af:panelWindow>
            </af:popup>
```

commit method:

```
    public void navigateWithCommit(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    System.err.println("before");
    ADFUtils.executeOperator("Commit");
    System.err.println("After");
    navigateMethod();
}
```

it shows below at log without commit

```
before
<oracle.adf.model> <QueryCollection> <clearNRT> <Initialized row(s) exists after commit, in collection:
TspGovernorateVO1
in ViewObject:
TspGovernorateVO1.
Application should ensure the created row is posted or removed, before commit.Removing row(s) from collection on commit.>
after
```

Comment: You say that you insert data into a form but I don't see any panelForm inside your popup. You could add a form or put your commit java logic inside the popup DialogEvent.

Comment: The form on the page, not at the popup. after inserting data in that form and navigate through menu to another page i catch if transaction is dirty so i show popup with 3 buttons to allow navigate and commit, navigate and rollback or just cancel.